# Getting the error "error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'stack' for a line of code that was previously working

Tags: r, spatial

I need to run this line of code to get some weather data for NY:

`weather = get_daymet(NY,label="precipitation", elements = c('prcp', 'tmin','tmax'), years = 2020:2021)`

This line of code has been working well for me for months, but now is not working and I get this message:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'stack': Problem creating coverage [prcp].

How can I fix this issue?